# Como ler um arquivo com Kotlin?

Tags: arquivo, kotlin

Tenho um arquivo `.txt` com algumas informações que eu gostaria de ler para uma string através do Kotlin.

Sou iniciante na linguagem e gostaria de saber como faço para ler um arquivo com Kotlin.

Comment: Igual ao Java :P

Comment: @bigown eu não sei como é no Java :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A maior parte da biblioteca de Kotlin é a mesma existente para o Java, um dos trunfos da linguagem já foi nascer com toda essa biblioteca disponível.

É possível [ler todo o arquivo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html) e depois manipulá-lo, [ler linhas](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html) dele, ou [ler do jeito que achar melhor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-bytes.html), ou ainda [ler por *streams*](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/reader.html). Toda [documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/index.html) do que pode fazer das mais variadas formas.

Enfim depende da necessidade. [Exemplos](http://kotlination.com/kotlin/read-file-kotlin).

#### Stream

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val inputStream: InputStream = File("kotlination.txt").inputStream()
 
    val inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    println(inputString)
}
```

#### Linha por linha

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
 
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val inputStream: InputStream = File("kotlination.txt").inputStream()
    val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
 
    inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines -> lines.forEach { lineList.add(it)} }
    lineList.forEach{println(">  " + it)}
}
```

#### BufferedReader

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.BufferedReader
 
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = File("kotlination.txt").bufferedReader()
 
    val inputString = bufferedReader.use { it.readText() }
    println(inputString)
}
```

#### Linha por linha

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.BufferedReader
 
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val bufferedReader = File("kotlination.txt").bufferedReader()
    val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
 
    bufferedReader.useLines { lines -> lines.forEach { lineList.add(it) } }
    lineList.forEach { println(">  " + it) }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/ReadFile.kt).

Answer (score 4):

(Quase) igual ao Java

É possível usar as bibliotecas do Java pra isso. Aliás, não só pra isso, boa parte da biblioteca da Kotlin é a do Java.

Obviamente existem diversas formas de trabalhar com arquivos. Um exemplo simples de como ler todas as linhas de um arquivo `.txt` é:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val stream: InputStream = File("wallace.txt").inputStream()

    val str = stream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    println(str)
}
```

Ou, então, ler linha por linha

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val stream: InputStream = File("wallace.txt").inputStream()
    val linhas = mutableListOf<String>()

    stream.bufferedReader().useLines { l -> l.forEach { linhas.add(it)} }

    linhas .forEach { println(">  " + it) }
}
```

**Obs**: Note que `it` é o nome padrão (implícito) do parâmetro de uma função anônima.

[Peguei os exemplos do Kotlination.](http://kotlination.com/kotlin/read-file-kotlin)